# Error in processing command in QProcess

Tags: qt, qprocess

I am trying to execute following command and trying to get the output however I am getting output as null.

```
    QProcess process;
    process.start("cmd /c \"ipconfig\"");
    process.waitForFinished(-1);
    QByteArray out = process.readAll();
    QString testStr = QString::fromUtf8(out);
```

Can someone please tell me where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check process.errorString()

Comment: I am getting "Unknown error" as error string.

Answer (score 0):

```
process.start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c \"ipconfig\"");
```

Comment: even this didn't work, don't know if this is a real problem or I am only facing this issue.

Comment: @sk100 you should set fullpath to `cmd.exe` or another process, anyway